# hyperref points wrong figure/table with reset counter

Tags: hyperref, counters, elsarticle

I am trying to refer tables (and figures) in the main text with numbering modified and reset as shown in MWE, the numbers are correct in the main text, but `hyperref` points to wrong table. How to get correct hyper reference to table and figures with reset counter?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}

\begin{document}

Table \ref{tb1} in main text. Table \ref{sm_tb1} in Supplementary Material.

\begin{table}
\caption{Main text table}\label{tb1}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

%--------------------------------
% Supplementary Material
%--------------------------------
\pagebreak
\section*{Supplementary Material}
\pagebreak
\pagebreak


\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{S\arabic{figure}}


\begin{table}
\caption{Supplemental table}\label{sm_tb1}
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
\hline
Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
\hline
2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
\hline
3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
\hline
4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
\hline
5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Resetting `table` or whatever counter especially in a unnumbered section must confuse `hyperref`, since this package creates 'unique' label names from section etc. counter values by applying the command `\theHtable`, for example. Now, since the table counter has the value `1` twice and no other unique value (like a section counter value) is available, the same anchor would be created.

It's sufficient, to provide a new `\theHtable` implementation for the supplement, making a new anchor name, say, `Supplement.`

```
\renewcommand{\theHtable}{Supplement.\thetable}
```

and the analogous form for the `\theHfigure` (see the code below)

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Table \ref{tb1} in main text. Table \ref{sm_tb1} in Supplementary Material.

\begin{table}
\caption{Main text table}\label{tb1}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 
 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

%--------------------------------
% Supplementary Material
%--------------------------------
\clearpage
\section*{Supplementary Material}
\clearpage

\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\theHtable}{Supplement.\thetable}
\renewcommand{\theHfigure}{Supplement.\thefigure}


\begin{table}
\caption{Supplemental table}\label{sm_tb1}
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
\hline
Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
\hline\hline
1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
\hline
2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
\hline
3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
\hline
4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
\hline
5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've omitted a screen shot here, since links aren't available anywhere in screen-shot

Comment: What about theorems in the appendix? It seems the same issue happens, can you use a similar solution? Thanks!