# Anchors in hyperref with algorithm2e and subfig

Tags: hyperref, algorithm2e, subfig

I am using **hyperref** to typeset a book containing many different research articles. Each article has its own set of theorems, definitions etc. and with every **\maketitle** the corresponding counters are reset, just as one would expect. Thus, there are multiple "Theorem 1" etc. This seems to be no problem for hyperref since they all have different anchors; everything is as it should be.

Now some of the articles contain algorithms typeset with **algorithm2e** and the counters for those are not reset by default, which is why I put a

```
\setcounter{algocf}{0}
```

in front of every article.  This changes the label, but I get

```
destination with the same identifier (name {algocf.1})
has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

and the hyperref link always points to the "first" Algorithm 1 etc.

I am afraid this solution (where figures and tables were considered) does not work for my problem:

[hyperref points wrong figure/table with reset counter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304814/hyperref-points-wrong-figure-table-with-reset-counter)

I tried

```
\renewcommand{\theHalgocf}{new.\thealgocf}
```

but to no avail.

The same problem appears with the **subfloat** command from the **subfig** package (here, counters are reset, but anchors are still ambiguous):

```
destination with the same identifier (name{subfigure.4.2})
has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{algorithm}{Algorithm}{Algorithms}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algo 1}\label{1}
  Test\;
\end{algorithm}

\setcounter{algocf}{0}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algo 2}\label{2}
  Test\;
\end{algorithm}

\Cref{1} and \cref{2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: By default, `\maketitle` does not reset counters, apart from `footnote`. By default, you can't use `\maketitle` more than once as well (well, you can, but it does nothing after the first usage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause for this problem is that `algorithm2e` redefines `\theHalgocf` in its `caption` wrapper again.

I've changed this to prepend a prefix to `\thealgocf` in `\theHalgocf` each time `\Maketitle` is called, which steps a `titlectr` counter, that resets the `algocf` counter as well.

`\Maketitle` is a wrapper for `\maketitle`, the later can't be used more than once without changing -- it is not shown how those changes are done by the O.P. to allow for more than one usage of `\maketitle`.

The regular `\maketitle` does not reset counters apart from `footnote`, however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\newcounter{titlectr}

\counterwithin*{algocf}{titlectr}

%\counterwithin*{subfig}{titlectr}% for subfigures



\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\long\def\algocf@caption@algo#1[#2]#3{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\algocf@algocfref}{\relax}}{}{\algocf@captionref}%
  \@ifundefined{hyper@refstepcounter}{\relax}{% if hyper@refstepcounter undefind, no hyperref, else...
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\algocf@algocfref}{\relax}}{\renewcommand{\theHalgocf}{\thetitlectr.\thealgocf}}{% take algocf as Href
      \renewcommand{\theHalgocf}{\thetitlectr.\algocf@algocfref}}%else if SetAlgoRefName done, take this name as ref.
    \hyper@refstepcounter{algocf}%set algocf as category of ref
  }%
   \algocf@latexcaption{#1}[{#2}]{{#3}}% call original caption
}%
}
\makeatother




\newcommand{\Maketitle}{%
  \stepcounter{titlectr}%
}


\title{foo}

\author{A. U. Thor}

\crefname{algorithm}{Algorithm}{Algorithms}

\begin{document}
\Maketitle

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algo 1}\label{1}
  Test\;
\end{algorithm}


\Maketitle

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algo 2}\label{2}
  Test\;
\end{algorithm}

\Cref{1} and \cref{2}.

\end{document}
```

Excerpts of `\jobname.aux`:

```
\@writefile{loa}{\contentsline {algocf}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Algo 1}}{1}{algocf.1.1}}
\newlabel{1}{{1}{1}{}{algocf.1.1}{}}
\newlabel{1@cref}{{[algorithm][1][]1}{[1][1][]1}}
\@writefile{loa}{\contentsline {algocf}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Algo 2}}{1}{algocf.2.1}}
\newlabel{2}{{1}{1}{}{algocf.2.1}{}}
\newlabel{2@cref}{{[algorithm][1][]1}{[1][1][]1}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  That worked like a charm.  I am sorry that I did not explain that I use a non-standard cls-file with \maketitle modified. Can I use the same strategy also for the counter subfigure or are there some more strings to pull since that counter in turn depends on the figure counter?

Comment: @Howard: Uncommenting my line for `\counterwithout*{subfigure}{titlecntr}` and `\renewcommand{\theHsubfig}{subfigure.\thetitlecntr.\thesubfigure}` should be sufficient, but this depends on the used subfigure code, i.e. the relevant package

Answer (score 1):

Had some similar problems in the past:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{figure}{Fig}{Figs}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Test1}\label{1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Test2}\label{2}
\end{figure}

\setcounter{figure}{0}

\pagebreak
\begin{figure}
\caption{Test3}\label{3}
\end{figure}

\Cref{1} and \cref{2}.

\Cref{3}.

\end{document}
```

This gives the error and second link Figure 1 doesnt work (ignored)

> pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier
>   (name{figure.1})  has been already used, duplicate ignored

By adding and using the caption or subcaption package problem solved:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\crefname{figure}{Fig}{Figs}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \captionof{figure}{Test1}\label{1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\captionof{figure}{Test2}\label{2}
\end{figure}

\setcounter{figure}{0}

\pagebreak
\begin{figure}
\captionof{figure}{Test3}\label{3}
\end{figure}

\Cref{1} and \cref{2}.

\Cref{3}.

\end{document}
```

Now everything works as expected.

PS: Sorry for changing the example but have not algorithm installed and could not test.

An alternative (in case it doesn't work even with `caption` or `subcaption`) was a command I had created like

```
\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldcaptionof\captionof
\renewcommand{\captionof}[2]{\ifx#1{figure}\captionsetup{type=figure}\else\ifx#1{table}\captionsetup{type=table}\else\ifx#1{algorithm}\captionsetup{type=algorithm}\else\ifx#1{subfigure}\captionsetup{type=subfigure}\else\ifx#1{subtable}\captionsetup{type=subtable}\else\ifx#1{subalgorithm}\captionsetup{type=subalgorithm}\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\oldcaptionof{#1}{#2}}}
```

But can't test it now because previous fix works for me